# Python find and replace questions in xml files

Tags: python, xml, replace

I want to modify several xml files (linguistic corpora) by adding a special element `<question>` to be able to operate more easily on strings representing questions.

Here is an example of a xml file I have:

```
<Turn speaker="spk2" startTime="4836.047" endTime="4840.004">
<Sync time="4836.047"/>
some text
<Sync time="4837.199"/>
first question ?
</Turn>
<Turn speaker="spk1" startTime="4840.004" endTime="4840.768">
<Sync time="4840.004"/>
text
<Event desc="rire" type="noise" extent="instantaneous"/>
</Turn>
<Turn speaker="spk2" startTime="4840.768" endTime="4846.534">
second question ?
<Sync time="4840.768"/>
third question? fourth question ? text
</Turn>
```

And the result I want:

```
<Turn speaker="spk2" startTime="4836.047" endTime="4840.004"><question>
<Sync time="4836.047"/>
some text
<Sync time="4837.199"/>
first question ?</question>
</Turn>
<Turn speaker="spk1" startTime="4840.004" endTime="4840.768">
<Sync time="4840.004"/>
text
<Event desc="rire" type="noise" extent="instantaneous"/>
</Turn>
<Turn speaker="spk2" startTime="4840.768" endTime="4846.534"><question>
second question ?</question><question>
<Sync time="4840.768"/>
third question?</question><question> fourth question ?</question> text
</Turn>
```

Basically, it has to replace every question mark with `?</question>`, and then go up in the text to find **either** another `?</question>` **or** an element `<Turn>`, and then add the opening `<question>` here.

The first element would also contain the string "some text", but this is what I want since I have no way to find the beginning of a question anyway.

I would really prefer to do that with python since I will have to use lxml library afterwards. And I'd also like to preserve the number of newlines from the original file.

I tried to do that with regex, but it seems a bit complicated since I have to consider newlines and also overlapping, besides having several groups. I came up with the following regex but that captures too much:

```
(</question>|<Turn.*>)([\s\S]*</question>)
```

I also tried something with a for loop on strings but being kind of new to python and programming in general I couldn't achieve what I want.

Comment: Is there any other punctuation like full stops or exclamation marks that you want to consider or do you you always want the question to start from the beginning of a turn?

Comment: No, I only need to find the preceding question mark (actually the closing element `</question>` since it is easy to replace "?" by `?</question>`) or the end of the `<Turn>` element if it intervenes between to questions.
Ideally I would also have to like a tag inside the question element indicating the line number of the file where the question begins (something like `<question line="48">`, which I guess would be easy to add afterwards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

# Using re.split with grouping parens so the separators get returned in the split results
chunk = re.split(r'(<Turn.*?>|\?)', original_text)

# The "<Turn...>" and "?" separators are at the odd indexes. These are the
# places that '<question>' and '</question>' need to be inserted.
for i in range(1, len(chunk), 2):
    if chunk[i] == '?':
        chunk[i-2] += '<question>'
        chunk[i] += '</question>'

new_text = ''.join(chunk)

print(new_text)
```